# Error while loading shared library libz.so.1 while cross compiling for arm-linux

Tags: compiling, gcc, shared-library, arm, cross-compilation

I'm trying to cross compile an opencv app on Ubuntu 14.04 to run on an ARM core. I can compile the open cv app fine on Ubuntu with

```
g++ test.c -o test -I /usr/include/opencv -I /usr/include/opencv2 -L /usr/local/lib/ -lopencv_core -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_highgui
```

It compiles and I have a testl.bin in my directory.

However, when I alter the compiler for my arm core

```
arm-linux-gnueabi-g++ test.c -o test -I /usr/include/opencv -I /usr/include/opencv2 -L /usr/local/lib/ -lopencv_core -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_highgui
```

I'm met with the error

```
error while loading shared libraries: libz.so.1: cannot open shared object file: no such file or directory.
```

When I try and install this library apt-get lets me know it's at it's newest version and there's nothing to be installed.

Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 12):

I had the same problem - it is a bit confusing. The cross-compiler may be 32-bit (my case), so it is complaining about missing 32-bit library:

```
sudo apt-get install zlib1g:i386
```

Then cross-compiler should work.

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem but the library suggested by @Marek had no installation candidates on my system. Instead, I solved the problem by running:

```
sudo apt-get install lib32z1
```

Comment: This solution works on my Ubuntu 16.04 Docker. The accepted answer doesn't.

Comment: Didn't work for redis-desktop-manager.rdm on Ubuntu 18.04. Still "error while loading shared libraries: libz.so.1"

Comment: This works on ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS

Comment: Exactly what I needed for being able to run precompiled `sqlite3` on Debian 9.